# Importing packages in Scala using sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm new to Scala and was trying to build a small project by sbt. Hovewer, it doesn't see my packages.

In structure  `myproject/src/main/scala` there is Main.scala, and a package subdirectory: `myproject/src/main/scala/packagefolder/Fruit.scala`(with "package packagefolder" on top included), package.scala (with a package object named packagefolder).

In sbt documentation i found out that sbt ignores other directories than scala during the compile ("Other directories in src/ [than main-resources, scala, java and test-resources, scala, java] will be ignored").
Somewhere else in the documentation they mentioned a way to include these, by implementing:

`def scalaSources(base: File): PathFinder = (base / "src") ** "*.scala"`

It doesn't mention where should I implement this though. All compiles and runs flawlessly when i put all the source files in the same directory - source.

Would somebody help me how do I include packages in elegant subdirectories? Or maybe there is another proper project structure in sbt. I'm totally new to Scala.

Comment: Your structure seems ok to me. Do you mean, for example, `Fruit` is not visible from `Main.scala`? Did you remember to `import packagefolder.Fruit` in `Main.scala`? The following command will setup the correct project structure:  `sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8`. Also consider https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/sbt-track/getting-started-with-scala-and-sbt-on-the-command-line.html

Comment: Yeah everything works now :) Structure was fine as You said, but I think I didn't start sbt from the project "home" directory - where the build is.